# If $g(x)=e^{-ax}f(x)$ with $a>0$ and it is known that $g(x)$ decreases in a region $x \geq 0$, then what can be said about $f(x)$ in the same region?

Tags: derivatives, inequality

I have one minor doubt, and that is, if lets say 
\begin{equation}
g(x)=e^{-ax}f(x)
\end{equation}
and $g(x)$ decreases in the region $x \geq 0$ i.e., $g'(x) \leq 0$, then what about $f(x)$. Can we say anything about $f(x)$? Whether $f(x)$ also decreases in that same region? or if it increases? Please help me understand this behaviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot say anything about monotonicity of $f$. Let $a=2$. Then $f(x)=e^{x}$ satisfies the hypothesis and $f$ is increasing. On the other hand $f(x)=e^{-x}$ also satisfies the hypothesis and $f$ is decreasing

Comment: ok thanks a lot! So, basically we cant comment on the monotonicity of $f(x)$ based on the monotonicity of $g(x)$?

Comment: @Amardeepmishra Yes. You can even construct an example where $f$ is increasing in some interval and decreasing in some other interval.